# Using cd command in Windows command line, can't navigate to D:\

Tags: windows, command-line, path, cd

This may be a silly question, and I think I have looked elsewhere to find the answer...  Might be a path issue, but when I open the command line and type from the `C:\>`:

```
cd D:\
```

I cannot get to the D drive.  Even if I type:

```
cd D:\<folder name>
```

The `command.exe` will auto-complete the line with the tab key, so it knows where I'm at.  It just doesn't print to screen the result or actually get me there.  This problem exists for the network drives as well.

Now, if I use the `chdir` (`cd`) command like this:

`chdir D:` or `cd d:`

I get the print out of the `D:\` below the command but it still says I'm in the `C:\`.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: I have been using `pushd` in place of `cd` pretty much everywhere as it behaves much better in situations like this.

Comment: See this answer "**cd /d D:**"  http://superuser.com/a/135239/78897

Comment: Try this:
cd /d d:

Answer (score 422, accepted):

Going back to the days of DOS, there's a separate "current directory" for each drive.  `cd D:\foldername` changes D:'s current directory to the foldername specified, but does not change the fact that you're still working on the `C:` drive.

What you want is simple:

```
D:
```

Here you can see how the "separate current directory for each drive" thing works:

```
C:\Users\coneslayer>e:

E:\>c:

C:\Users\coneslayer>cd e:\software

C:\Users\coneslayer>e:

e:\Software>
```

Comment: also `cd e:` outputs `e:\Software` after those commands

Answer (score 87):

### It *did* work, as the command is designed to work.

You simply don't know how it's actually supposed to work.

You're not using a Unix or Linux shell program.  The `cd` command in Microsoft's command interpreter doesn't behave as the `cd` commands in such shells do.  It behaves somewhat differently.  In particular, *it doesn't always change directory*.  In Unix and Linux shells, `cd` only ever sets the working directory.  In Microsoft's command interpreter, `cd` sometimes queries it.  There's no separate `pwd` command, so `cd` does two jobs.

If you give it no arguments, or an argument that is just a drive letter and a colon without a path, then *it reports the current directory instead of changing it*.  If you give it no arguments, it reports the current directory of the current drive of the command interpreter process.  If you give it only a drive letter and a colon as an argument, it reports the command interpreter process' current directory of that drive.  Each drive has its own current directory in the command interpreter.  (This is a fiction maintained by the run-time libraries for Microsoft's and several other vendors' implementations of various programming languages.  Win32 itself doesn't work this way.)

So when you gave it `d:` as an argument, it reported the the command interpreter process' current directory on drive D to you, which happened to be `D:\`.  If you'd given it no arguments at all, it would have reported `C:\` to you.

If you want the `cd` command to *always be in set mode and never be in query mode* you need to add the `/D` option to it.  This forces the command to always be in set mode, and also extends it so that it changes the current drive as well as changing a drive's current directory.  (In other words, it works more like the underlying Win32 API actually does.)

So, for example, the command line

```
cd /d d:
```

will change directory to whatever the current directory on drive D is, and also change the current drive to drive D.

If you want to change the command interpreter process' current drive otherwise, the `cd` command is not the way.  You do so by simply typing the drive letter and a colon:

```
d:
```

#### Further reading

- JP Software (2011). [*CD/CHDIR*](http://jpsoft.com./help/cd.htm) TCC On-line Help.
- Microsoft corporation (2001). [*Chdir (CD)*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490875.aspx).  TechNet Windows XP Command line reference A–Z.

Comment: [Related post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx).

Comment: Not completely right. If you do `cd d:\ ` it changes the working directory on `d:`. If you do `d:\ ` afterwards it will be at `d:\ `. If you do `cd d:\something\something` nothing will happen at first. But if you do `d:\ ` afterwards again, your path will be `d:\something\something"`!

Comment: None of which contradicts what is written above in any way, `sinni800` (apart from your getting the syntax for changing current drive wrong, that is, but I'll overlook that).  I didn't include discussion of what happens when one supplies a pathname in an argument because (a) that's not what the question is about and (b) it's in the further reading.

Comment: No, we're not.  It would be wrong to talk of partitions instead of drives here, `user unknown`.  For starters, partitions are not the same as volumes, and drive letters map to volumes, not partitions.  And when one is talking at this level of abstraction, _drive letter_ and _current drive_ are the conventional terms, as used here, in the further reading indicated, and even in the `cd /?` help text.

Comment: I have used this command for at least 20 years and never knew this.

Comment: Since you're providing a hyperlink to JP Software's online help, you may also want to refer to [JP Software's online help for their "CDD" command](http://jpsoft.com./help/cdd.htm), as that is quite relevant to this conversation.

Answer (score 73):

Afraid this is incorrect.  It's true from the days of DOS, but the command line in Windows NT and later is not DOS.  In the command line that everyone uses today, you have the /D switch.  The /d switch will change the current directory of the specified drive AND change to that directory.  The /d switch must be specified before the path. For example:

```
C:\> cd /d D:\foo\bar\
D:\foo\bar\>
```

[image: windows command prompt cd]

Comment: +1 because I learned something new, but I don't think that anything I wrote is incorrect.

Comment: Your answer is correct too, Multiverse IT, but coneslayer wasn't incorrect.  Thanks for your efforts.  I learned two great tricks on this question.

Comment: From my perspective "What you want is simple ... D:" is incorrect.  Yes it works and is a valid method of achieving the goal, but it is not, strictly speaking what he should want.  Additionally, the way the comment is worded implies that you cannot use CD to do this - that implication is incorrect.

Comment: his main issue is to "I cannot get to the D drive.". As such, the other answer is correct. Your solution takes simply one step less (which is good). It doesn't make the other one incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, "what he should want."  Sounds rather presumptive ;-)

Comment: typing just C: to change to the C: drive in Windows 10 worked

Answer (score 21):

***CD*** stands for **C**hange **D**irectory, and not Change Drive. So it would not change to D: like that. To achieve this you'd have to simply type in the drive letter

e.g.

> **d:**

Comment: cd /D D: changes drives and directories...

Comment: But d: is a partition, not a drive.

Comment: @userunknown In the Dos 1.0 era when the shell was designed there were only floppy disks which AFAIK can't be partitioned.  Initial hardrive support was only for the primary (first) partition on a  drive.  Extended partition support wasn't added until later.

Comment: I don't see a MS-DOS 1.0 tag, nor 1.0 mentioned. Maybe you can't partition a drive with MS-DOS programs, but you can install an MS-DOS on a partitioned drive. I guess MS-DOS is out of support though, and the tag is there, because many users believe that cmd.exe and MS-DOS means the same, which is another error to address. Apropos: MS-DOS 1.0 was never published.

Comment: @userunknown The design decisions date back to the initial versions of DOS.  Changing behavior would have broken older programs (see Daniel Beck's comment below).  PS; according to Wikipedia MS DOS 1.x was published.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
cd /D D:
```

to do this. You can specify paths also.

Answer (score 9):

The working directory in cmd.exe is maintained on a `volume-by-volume` basis; the Working Directory for the `C:` drive is different from the working directory for the  `D:` drive.

When you pass only a drive letter to `cd`, it will print the working directory for the specified drive.

In your case, the working directory of the `D:` drive is the volume root itself, `D:\`.

To change volumes from `C:` to `D:` simply enter the drive letter:

```
C:\>D:
D:\>
```

Comment: cd /D D: changes drives and directories...

Comment: Partitions are mapped to a drive letter, and are virtually the same as a drive.  You can also map a directory or share to a drive, and they behave the same.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change drive in a DOS command prompt then you simply have to write:

```
[Drive Letter]:
```

For example, if you want to move to the D:\ drive then you just have to type the following 
in a command prompt:

```
D:
```

Comment: You change the partition with `[Drive Letter]:`, believe me or test it out!

Comment: Oh wow, that makes things a hell of a lot easier. I always forget the `/d` so this makes switching much faster.

Answer (score 2):

`pushd` works even when you need to go to drive sub directory e.g. `D:\Tests\Logs`.

Just use it so:

```
pushd D:\Tests\Logs
```

If you want to go back to previous directory use `popd`:

```
C:\Users>pushd D:\Tests\Logs
D:\Tests\Logs>popd
C:\Users>
```

Answer (score -1):

While you going to search option in the tool bar and search for cmd or by selecting windows All app selecting command prompt then it takes to some other command prompt.

Instead try pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and search for `cmd`, it takes to `C:\>` drive. From there you can navigate to `D:\>` or anywhere you need