# change directory command doesn't work in windows command prompt

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can’t Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

Somehow cd command is not working in windows command prompt when I want to change the drive.

For example if I'm in:

`C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools>`

with command

`cd d:\`

It doesnt take me to `d:` drive but it stays in

`C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools>`

If I try `cd..` or `cd\` or trying to change the directory within the drive that works.

Any help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When changing drives, you just need to type the drive letter, like `d:` (EDIT: don't use the backslash, like `d:\`; it doesn't work).  You only use `cd` when moving between directories within a drive.

Comment: Actually, `D:\ ` (extra space to escape the slash) does not work. Only `D:` does.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I just caught that.

Answer (score 44):

If you are going into a folder on another drive, why not simply type

> cd /d d:\someFolder\anotherFolder

The /d switch is specified in `cd /?`

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive.

Comment: Worked for me! Though I'm finding myself wishing it wasn't so picky.

Comment: This worked for me even when `cd d:` didn't, thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Agree, this should be the accepted answer. This is more clear and worked for me.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure why I only noticed this now, to be honest it's slightly annoying

Answer (score 4):

This is a known 'feature' dating back to the DOS ages. Put simply, you have one 'active directory' for each drive. `cd` changes the active directory for that drive only. For example, `cd C:\WINDOWS` changes the active directory of the `C:` drive to `\WINDOWS`. To change to another drive, you would use something like `A:` to change to the A drive.

Answer (score 4):

Other option:
pushd d:\

for return to a previos directory:
popd

is possible also, go to a "unc" directory, for example:
(creates a temporary Z: drive)
pushd \\localhost\mydir