# Can't CD to a subfolder in ramdisk (DOS window in windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change directory command doesn’t work in windows command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/165364/change-directory-command-doesnt-work-in-windows-command-prompt)

I have a ramdisk on t: drive in Windows 7 64bit.  It has a folder called temp. I can't do a CD t:\temp in a DOS window. There's no error message. the command returns with a prompt at the same c: folder where I issued the command. If I do t: it switches to t drive. The CD however doesn't switch to that drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/165364/change-directory-command-doesnt-work-in-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CD only Changes the Directory, it doesn't change to another drive.

Thus the correct sequence is:

```
T:
cd Temp
```

If you want to type that on one line for some reason:

```
T: && cd Temp
```

Comment: Actually if you do the /D switch it will change your drive `cd /D T:\Temp`