# Why is cd in Windows not able to switch between drives?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can’t Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

Why, just why, is `cd` in Windows so stupid and does not do what it's supposed to do in the situations like this:

```
I:\Documents and Settings\blah\>cd C:\somedir\
I:\Documents and Settings\blah\>
```

I know you can `chdir /d`. But why is that not the default behavior?

Comment: @kinokijuf: don't edit the tags if you don't know what they mean.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate. The "duplicate" asks *how*, not *why*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is by design. Each "drive" has it's own working directory. You can use `chdir`, or you can simply type the drive letter:

`> D:`

And that will change to the D drive. If you want to know why this behavior exists, see [Raymond Chen's Explanation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563)

Comment: As the blog says, `s/has/used to have/`, and the `cmd` shell emulates this behavior.

Comment: Basically, because cd is change directory, not change drive.

Answer (score 12):

In windows could use the native **`cd/d <drive>:<path>`** or else **`chdir/d`** or **`pushd`**.  It is the **`/d`** option that indicates that the drive should change as well.  The **`pushd`** command does this by default.

Can even alias cd to make that the default behavior like so:

```
doskey cd=chdir/d $*
```

Then can use do things like:

```
cd D:\Temp
cd C:\WINDOWS
```

and the drive will change as well.

See the help by entering **`cd/?`** for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's a historical thing. `cd` only changes current directory on the drive that is specified (current if none), and `<drive>:` changes drives to the folder **on that drive** which was `cd`'d earlier (`\` if none)

Answer (score 1):

some 3rd party shells - like 4dos has CDD command for this

You can create a batch file called "cdd.bat" in your main Windows directory with the following line:

```
@cd /d %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Now, you can do the following with the new CDD command:

C:>cdd d:

D:>cdd c:\documents and settings

C:\Documents and Settings>cdd d:\data

D:\data>

Comment: How about `@cd /d %*`