# `cd` doesn't change directory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can’t Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)
>   [CMD cd to other drives except C:\ not working](https://superuser.com/questions/302505/cmd-cd-to-other-drives-except-c-not-working)

I am working with `cmd.exe` on Windows 7 (as opposed to Powershell).  I have 2 partitions on my drive, C contains the OS and installed programs, and D contains my data.  I was trying to `cd` from C to D, but cmd wouldn't let me:

```
C:\>cd D:\

C:\>
```

However, when I type `dir D:\`, it will list the contents of D correctly.  Why does it do this and how can I fix it?  Powershell works fine so I can use that, but I would like to know what makes `cmd` misbehave.

Comment: Could someone make an msdos tag? I think this question is valid for all versions of DOS from 1.0 and up. If I recall correctly CP/M didn't have this concept but you could address the separate drives by prepending the driveletter: to the file name. I think this is important as this is a valid question for someone who didn't live through the DOS era and not a Windows 7 question as such.

Comment: @StuartWoodward actually DOS 1.0 did not have subdirectories - they were introduced in 2.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to use just `d:`  , not `cd d:\`

**EDIT:** it is also possible to use `cd /d d:` to change drives using cd

Comment: I am not really sure why made that design decision, and I am looking for it, but that's just the way that it has always been.

Comment: @astay13 see edit.

Comment: @soandos `cd` stands for "change directory", and `D:` is a drive, not a directory.  See David's answer for more details

Comment: @Izkata why cant you change to a directory on a different drive using the same syntax used to go to a different folder? that is what I was saying.

Comment: It does change the directory: e.g.: C:\>cd D:\test, does change the current directory on disk D: to test, but the prompt is still on C:

Comment: @soandos The only advantage to this scheme is that sometimes it is convenient to have a working directory on more than one drive. For example, if you're trying to copy files from c:\<long_path> to d:\<other_long_path> you can go to drive D, cd to the long path, then go to drive C, cd to the long path, and then just copy to 'D:'. Then you can go back to drive D and cd relative to the long path without retyping it.

Comment: You can't really ask why DOS works the way it does. It provided the minimum set of commands to manage your files without wasting space on your 16K of memory or 160K floppy drive.

Answer (score 28):

Windows tracks a separate working directory for each drive. You are currently on the 'C' drive in the working directory '\'. When you type `cd d:\` it changes your working directory for the 'D' drive to '\' and has no effect on your C drive working directory. To change drives, just type `D:`. You can change both at the same time with the `/d` parameter to `cd`.

Comment: Actually, the Windows that the questioner says that xe is running — Windows NT 6.1 — has _never_ — not since 1993 — had a separate working directory for each drive.  There is _one_ working directory per process.  The _appearance_ of multiple working directories across multiple drives is a fiction maintained by Microsoft's command interpreter and the runtime libraries of its languages, using hidden environment variables.

Comment: [Obligatory vaguely-related link to Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx)

Comment: @JdeBP Hidden environment variables that track a separate working directory for each drive? And is Microsoft's command interpreter and the runtime libraries of its languages part of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that [`pushd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771180%28WS.10%29.aspx) (e.g. `pushd D:\`) will always change drives.

Comment: This would be wonderful as a comment to the question but doesn't answer the question.