# cmd.exe shortcuts and parameters issue

Tags: windows, command-line

When I try to run the following code:

`C:\WINNT\System32\cmd.exe /k cd  "C:\page\app" & start1.bat

it throws the following error message:

`The system cannot find the path specified.
'start1.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

How about you put the CD in the batch file and call it using

```
C:\WINNT\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\page\app\start1.bat"
```

To make the batch file use a random path, you could add this for the cd:

```
cd %~dp0
```

It will cd to whatever the calling path is

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole value of `/k` parameter in double quotes and it will work:

```
C:\WINNT\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd /d C:\page\app & start1.bat"
```

I added `/d` switch after `cd` to make sure it also changes the current drive, not only current directory on C drive (see [`cd` doesn't change directory in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/361802/cd-doesnt-change-directory-in-windows-7))