# Can't change current working directory to external drive in Windows

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can’t Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)
>   [CMD cd to other drives except C:\ not working](https://superuser.com/questions/302505/cmd-cd-to-other-drives-except-c-not-working)

I'm trying to run a program located on an external USB disk using the Windows command prompt. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit (running in VMWare Workstation 8.0.)

Here's what happens:

1. I plug in the USB disk and it appears as drive letter 'E' in My
   Computer.
2. I launch `cmd` from the start menu.
3. I notice the prompt
   displays `C:\Users\Tom>`
4. I type `cd E:\`
5. I notice the prompt displays
   `C:\Users\Tom>` (`cd` also yields `C:\Users\Tom>`)

I can explore the drive using explorer.exe just fine, and it is connected according to VMWare Workstation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you type `cd e:\` you are changing the current working directory (**CWD**) for drive **E:**, but you are not currently on that drive.
To go to drive E:, just type: `E:` and hit enter.

You can change the **CWD** of any drive without being on it, as you can change drives at anytime by just typing the drive letter followed by colon (**:**).

This is expected behavior since the very first versions of MS-DOS (and probably all other DOS OS), as for Windows as it's successor.

Comment: If you were to type `cd e:\foo` while still on the C drive, then typed `e:` you would find that the folder would change not to `e:\>` but to `e:\foo>`  May seem silly, but it can be useful when you need to copy several things to a long DOS path.  Change the path, then you can just type `copy bar.txt e:` and it will go to the path you specified, rather than the root of e: and without having to re-specify the path.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of changing the CWD of different drive ;)

Answer (score 7):

To change to a different drive *and* simultaneously specify a directory in that drive you can use the "/d"-parameter like this: `cd /d E:\` This will take you to the root directory of E: