# Can't "cd" to virtualbox shared folder in cmd.exe

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CMD cd to other drives except C:\ not working](https://superuser.com/questions/302505/cmd-cd-to-other-drives-except-c-not-working)
>   [Can’t change current working directory to external drive in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/441491/cant-change-current-working-directory-to-external-drive-in-windows)

I have a Linux host and a WindowsServer2008 guest. In this guest, if I try to

```
cd E:/
```

(same as `E:\` )

I can't (still in my "home"). See :

[image]

Am I missing something or there's a problem somewhere ?

(I'm more familiar with Unix tools)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. It is related, but completely different. A shared folder is a network drive, not an external drive. That said, based on the provided answers and acceptance, it is not about shared folders at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you just enter the drive name. So instead of `cd E:\` you would just enter `E:`.

Answer (score 2):

cmds `cd` normally allows you to change only within current drive. If you want to switch drive at the same time, you'd have to use `/d` switch: `cd /d e:\` would work.  And you should use backslash `\` instead of forward slash `/` for paths :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it should be : `cd /d e:` to work correctly =)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do; `cd /d e:` has the same effect as `e:`; both will move you to whatever current directory drive e: was set to (it does not need to be e:\, it may be `e:\something`). To move to different drive and set it's current directory at the same time, you should use `cd /d path`

Comment: I mean `cd /d e:\` doesn't cd to E: but fails.

Comment: Strange, it should work, but probably deserves it's own question if it's something you'd like further explained. Btw if you want to see full cd (or other internal cmds) syntax, just enter 'help cd' at the prompt