# Opening cmd in a particular disk in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, cmd.exe, path

I want to track a file on hard drive "D", while cmd is always opening to hard drive "C" by default.

As you see, I have a file in hard drive "D", but I want to track it on cmd. However I can't because cmd is on hard drive "C" by default.

[image]

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMD cd to other drives except C:\ not working](http://superuser.com/questions/302505/cmd-cd-to-other-drives-except-c-not-working)

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "track a file"?  (2) What is `D:\ANDROID\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools`?  Is it a command?  (`platform-tools` is an unusual name for a command.)  What do you get if you type `dir D:\ANDROID\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools`?  If you get a "File Not Found" error, try it again, with an added `*` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Enter

```
D:
```

that should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

```
cd D:\folder\subfolder\directory
```

cd stands for *Change Directory*

if you want to open the cmd prompt at this location, create a shortcut to cmd, but set the start-in location to D:.. whatever your path was.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting cmd with the following command:

```
cmd /k D:
```