# Windows 7: Command Prompt won't CD into a network mapped drive

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

When I'm in cmd, I try to go to a mapped network drive that i have such as cd x:\ or cd y:\ and it executes with no error and just gives me back to C:\Users\Adam.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`cd` is primarily for changing directories, you're trying to change drives.

from the command prompt type `z:` or `cd /D z:`

for clarification on cd and it's options type `cd /?` from the command prompt.