# Why wouldn't cd <drive letter>: work?

Tags: command-line, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

I am in the C partition and I type at the prompt:

```
c:\> cd d:
```

... and it echoes:

```
d:\

c:\>
```

...so it gets back to `c:\`.

Why is this happening?