# While changing directory in Windows 7, cmd changes it to previously typed location. Why?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)
>   [Why wouldn't cd <drive letter>: work?](https://superuser.com/questions/380105/why-wouldnt-cd-drive-letter-work)

This is what I found when trying to go from one directory to another in windows7 using cmd. Reproduced below (in bolds) is the terminal and later I explain my question

**C:> cd k:\folder1\folder2**

**C:>k:**

**k:\folder1\folder2>****

In the first line, it did not allowed me to enter into the desired location. 
In second line, when I just wanted to go into the k directory, it sent me to the address which I typed in previous command.

Question: Why, in second command, on just typing 'k:', i find myself in 'k:\folder1\folder2'?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick answer:  `C:>k: ` is still in C:, you can't cd across drives.  You switch drives by using the /D switch.

Comment: I do not understand the > In the first line, it did not allowed me to enter into the desired location. part of your question, Could you elaborate further? As for the second part of the question, have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx) article, it clearly explains: > In second line, when I just wanted to go into the k directory, it sent me to the address which I typed in previous command. > Question: Why, in second command, on just typing 'k:', i find myself in 'k:\folder1\folder2'?

Comment: Thanks. Second question (Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:), while not the same, has the top answer which answers my question. Here is the link for the answer. http://superuser.com/a/135217/120951

Comment: No one here has quite answered the question correctly.  To understand why this happens, we need a time machine. I'll let Raymond Chen tell you why this is the case: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The command shell retains values for the current drive, and the current directory *on each drive*. When you type `CD`, it only changes the current directory for the current drive or the specified drive.  Changing to a drive will put you in that drive's current directory.

To change drive and directory at once, you can use:

```
CD /D K:\folder1\folder2
```

Also, you can use this method to use shorthand in other commands:

```
CD J:\folderA\folderB
CD K:\folder1\folder2
Copy J:*.* K:
```

Will copy all files from `J:\folderA\folderB` to `K:\folder1\folder2`, even if you're in the C: drive.  Note the lack of slashes in the `Copy` command.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `cd` and specify a full path, with drive letter, it changes the working directory for that drive.  It will not by default switch you over to that drive, however.  This allows you to execute some commands on the other drive, using programs in the current path, without having to type the whole path for the other drive into command parameters.

Consider the following example, where you have not included your MyBatchFiles folder in `%PATH%`, and you've got to run a script against some files deep in the file system on D:.  Here, the script is just `copy %1 %2` but it really could be anything that needs to work on an arbitrary target on another drive.  See how execution of this command on subsequent files requires much less typing than if I'd had to specify the full path every time.

---

[image]

---

Now, if you really want to change to a directory on another drive *and* switch to that drive, you just need to use the `/d` switch.  See below.

---

[image]

---