# cd not doing anything in the Windows Shell

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can’t Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

[image: image of prob]

Look at the latter lines of the shell, the `cd` lines.

Nothing's happening :(

This is the Win8 shell. I used to have Win7 on C:\, and have since installed Win8 on D:. As you can see, the prompt is in C:\, and so I'm trying to move it to D:\ where it should be. And nothing's happening.

**How can I change the directory?** (Bonus points to anyone who can tell be how to change the default shell directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing changed since the DOS day, you just need to type `D:` to change to D drive.

[image: Shell changing to D]