# How to use the cd command in Windows Powershell to change the drive that I am working

Tags: powershell

I read [this](https://superuser.com/a/135217/227880) answer but it doesn't work for Windows PowerShell. How to change the drive?

EDIT:
Please ignore this question. I was trying to change the drive from C: to D:. The reason it wasn't working was that there was no D: on my computer. A really silly mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:∖](http://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

Comment: @Excellll It's not, the question you linked to talks about the native shell (cmd), not PowerShell.

Comment: BTW, You should save as a *.ps1 file to run in PowerShell...  i.e. 

    Set-Location C:\Folder

Answer (score 46, accepted):

PowerShell will resolve full paths just fine with CD.

Where in DOS you have to /d for drive changing:

```
cd /d H:\Folder
```

PowerShell you can just type the full path:

```
cd H:\Folder
```

Comment: You can also use: `Set-Location -Path "D:\Toni"`.

Answer (score -1):

It’s the same as the DOS shell “cd *dir*”

Comment: `cd dir` won't work if `dir` is on another drive.

Comment: Use the /d switch

Comment: Sure, that's what I gathered from Austin T French's answer. But having to add `/d` is not obvious at all (to me at least), meaning that information should be part of the answer. Put another way: `cd dir` is not the same as `cd /d dir`