# Windows 10 Command Prompt system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, shared-folders

### Environment

Windows 10 1511 Stable Release
UAC Disabled
[image: Disabled UAC]
I have a C:
and an M: mounted from another Windows Machine

### Issue

I can view, edit & delete contents of M: without any issues when using Windows Explorer

But when i try to access the same via command prompt

M:
or 
cd M: both have same error

I got the following error
"The System Cannot Find the file Specified"

[image: Error Screenshot]

### Impact

i have many batch scripts that relies on the M: drive and they don't work anymore

### What i have tried so Far

1. Rebooted the machines

Comment: `CMD` with admin right or not?

Comment: Yes attached screenshot of the error, Also UAC disabled so CMD opens as Administrator even regularly, but same way issue when i right click and select "run As administrator"

Comment: Are you sure that UAC disabled, but not in auto-allow mode?

Comment: Have you tried "cd M:"?

Comment: yes cd M: same result attached screenshot of UAC

Comment: just fixed my issue updating the answer

Comment: Thanks for the comments, your comments kept me going in testing in further

Comment: `cd /d M:` would be the correct command in cmd.exe (see also https://superuser.com/questions/610787/how-to-use-the-cd-command-in-windows-powershell-to-change-the-drive-that-i-am-wo/610789#610789)

Comment: What does this have to do with UAC? I just started having this issue and I don't know what changed. I cannot access any files, create new files or directories from the command line even when running as Admin. No issues when using File Explorer.

Comment: Just marked the solution which worked give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even thought i had disabled UAC from Control Panel > User Accounts > Change User Account Control Settings to Never Notify but it still didn't help

I had to disable the UAC from registry, this i remember from working on a HP software where it specifically told to [disable from registry](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Registry-Key-to-Disable-UAC-45d0df25)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>
> In the details pane (Right Pane)
>
> locate the EnableLUA key (REG_DWORD type).
>
> Double click to Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type 0 (zero),
>
> and then click OK.
>
> restart the computer.

Comment: this breaks the new store apps, this is why moving slider down since Win8 no longer disables UAC completely.

Comment: Can you provide specifics which app broke it so i can test that as well? I don't use much apps but still would like to confirm

Comment: All apps from the Windows store don't work if UAC is disabled via EnableLUA  set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking whether Command Prompt can recognize it or not by using the diskpart command and then list volume.

It will show all activated drives on your Windows computer that Command Prompt can recognize.

```
diskpart
list volume
```